# my store is not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux and react-redux.

I have a huge list of data which are the occupations of a user.

I have this container that is connected to the redux via connect of react-redux.

```
// ChangeOccupations.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import ChangeOccupation from '../../../../components/pages/admin/subs/ChangeOccupation';

import {
    occupation_update
} from '../../../../actions/edit';

class ChangeOccupations extends Component {
    render() {
        let occupations = this.props.occupations.map((occupation, i) => <ChangeOccupation occupation={occupation} original={occupation} index={i} key={i} occupationUpdate={this.props.occupationUpdate} />);

        return (
            <div>
                <p className="title">Change Your Occupations</p>

                {occupations}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(store) {
    return {
        occupations: store.edit.occupations
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        occupationUpdate: payload => dispatch(occupation_update(payload))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChangeOccupations);
```

then a component.

```
// ChangeOccupation.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ChangeOccupation extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.changeCompany = this.changeCompany.bind(this);
        this.changeFreelance = this.changeFreelance.bind(this);
    }

    changeCompany(event) {
        let value = event.target.value;

        this.props.occupationUpdate({
            index: this.props.index,
            occupation: {
                ...this.props.occupation,
                company: value
            }
        });
    }

    changeFreelance() {
        console.log(this.props.occupation.freelance);

        if(this.props.occupation.freelance == 1) {
            return this.props.occupationUpdate({
                index: this.props.index,
                occupation: {
                    ...this.props.occupation,
                    freelance: 0
                }
            });
        }

        return this.props.occupationUpdate({
            index: this.props.index,
            occupation: {
                ...this.props.occupation,
                freelance: 1
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.occupationUpdate);

        return (
            <form method="post" action="">
                <ul className="ul-blocked-li">
                    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Company name..." value={this.props.occupation.company? this.props.occupation.company: ''} onChange={this.changeCompany} /></li>
                    <li><input type="text" placeholder="Job title..." value={this.props.occupation.title} onChange={this.changeCompany} /></li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="hidden" value={this.props.occupation.freelance} />
                        <input id="freelance" type="checkbox" onChange={this.changeFreelance} />
                        <label htmlFor="freelance">I am a freelancer</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default ChangeOccupation;
```

so the container is connected to redux and it will receive all the occupations data and the dispatches. It will then render all the occupations data via the `this.props.occupations.map()` using the `<ChangeOccupation />` component which will receive all the props and dispatches, you can see it on this line:

```
let occupations = this.props.occupations.map((occupation, i) => <ChangeOccupation occupation={occupation} original={occupation} index={i} key={i} />);
```

the problem is that when the `<ChangeOccupation/>` component dispatches an action it doesn't seem to update or anything, but it does reach the reducer. What could be the possible problems?

Comment: What does the reducer do to the state?

Comment: Share you reducer's code

Comment: Share your Action and reducer code ?